# How to check condition for date greater than or smaller than in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, date

here inputtext gives the value entered in the textbox and hidden field value returns current value.

My code till now:

```
if (inputText.value.length != 0) {
    if (inputText.value < document.getElementById('<%=HdnDate.ClientID%>').value) {
        alert("Please ensure that the Date is greater than or equal to the Current Date.");
        inputText.value = "";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is currently happening?

Comment: This might help [Compare dates with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dateObj = new Date();
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth();
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
    var dateSplitArray = "";
    var enddate = '05/05/2014'; // set your date here from txtbox
    var IsValidDate = false;
    splitString(enddate, "/");
    if (year >= dateSplitArray[2]) {
        if (month >= dateSplitArray[1]) {
            if (day >= dateSplitArray[0]) {
                IsValidDate = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (IsValidDate == false) {
        alert("Please ensure that the Date is greater than or equal to the Current Date.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Please proceed, no issue with date");
    }
    function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
        dateSplitArray = stringToSplit.split(separator);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: my date format is ex:4-may-2014. how to check for mothng?in the above code@nayeemkhan

Comment: But only one thing we can add when month is eqau and when month is greater condition. if (dateSplitArray[2] >= year) {
               
                if (monthNumber = month) {
                    if (dateSplitArray[0] >= day) {                        
                        IsValidDate = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (monthNumber >month)
                { IsValidDate = true; }@nayeemkhan

Comment: Why use UTC values? If a user at say UTC-0500 runs the above at 21:00 on 30 June, the above will return UTC values for 1 July. Also, month numbers in ECMAScript are zero based, this answer doesn't allow for that (e.g. `date.getMonth()` returns 5 for June).

Comment: @sona in case of 4-may-2014, u may need to maintain an array of month name to compare months, thanks.

Comment: @RobG It was my choice to go for UTC as date retrieval is simple. you can convert or use any other format too, no restriction :). For month please add 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input date is in a format like d/m/y, then you can convert that to a date object using:

```
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/g);
  return new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
}
```

which creates a date object for 00:00:00 on the specified date.

To compare to the current date, create a new Date object and set the time to 00:00:00.0:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Then convert the string to a Date and compare the two:

```
var otherDay = parseDate('21/4/2013');

console.log(otherDay + ' less than ' + today + '?' + (otherDay < today)); // ... true
```

#### Edit

It seems your date format is 4-may-2014. In that case:

```
function parseDate(s) {
  var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:12};
  var b = s.split(/-/g);
  return new Date(b[2], months[b[1].substr(0,3).toLowerCase()], b[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var d1= new Date(); // get the current date

var enddate = inputText.value; // text box value

var d2 = enddate.split('/');

d2 = new Date(d2.pop(), d2.pop() - 1, d2.pop());


if (d2 >= d1)
 {
    // do something
 }
```

Comment: Assuming that *d1* is actually *startdate*, note that *startdate* will use the current time whereas *d2* will not and be set to 00:00:00. So even if *d2* and *startdate* are the same date, `d2 >= d1` will almost certainly always be false unless *startdate* is created at exactly midnight (to the millisecond 00:00:00.000) at the start of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var date1=inputText.value;
var date2=document.getElementById('<%=HdnDate.ClientID%>').value;
var record1 = new Date(date1);
var record2 = new Date(date2);
if(record1 <= record2)
{
      alert("Please ensure that the Date is greater than or equal to the Current Date.");

}
```

Comment: But how it will check for month and year?@joker

Comment: it will check for whole date not just for day, i just use variable name record_day1

Comment: Thanks for the reply.let me try.@joker

Comment: For alert message record1 and record2 it is showing invalid date.@joker

Comment: It does not make any sense at all to get the parts of a date, then construct a non–standard string that is then parsed by *Date.parse*. Just use the parts directly in the Date constructor. E.g. assuming a standard d/m/y string: `record1 = new Date(record_day1[2], --record_day1[1], record_day1[0])`.

Comment: change my answer try this, may be it helps you. . .@sona